# A simple question regarding $df(E)$ for $f(A)=A^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, random-matrices

I am trying to follow the document on http://web.mit.edu/people/raj/Acta05rmt.pdf, and I got a simple question that
why for  $f(A)=A^{-1}$ we have $df(E)=-A^{-1}EA^{-1}$ on page 5?   (where $E$ is a small perturbation, and on page 4 the author says the $df$ is just the jacobian matrix.  )

I got a method which seems correct:   $df(A^{-1})=d(A^{-1})=-A^{-1}dfA^{-1}$, and substitute $E$ for $df$.

But my question is why another method would not work: I think the correct way to calculate jacobian is to find the derivative of $f(A+E)$ with respect to $E$, which I found somehow would not lead to the correct answer (a quick check is that the derivative of matrix wrt matrix would result in a squared size dimension matrix) ?

Thanks.

Following up : besides Raskolnikov's explane, there is also explanation here: http://web.mit.edu/18.325/www/handouts/handout2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$, we have

$$f(A+E)=(A+E)^{-1}=(\mathbb{I}+A^{-1}E)^{-1} A^{-1} \; .$$

Using a series development for the first factor

$$(\mathbb{I}+A^{-1}E)^{-1} = \mathbb{I}-A^{-1}E+\ldots$$

we obtain

$$f(A+E)=(A+E)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}E A^{-1}+\ldots$$

thus

$$df(E)=f(A+E)-f(A)=-A^{-1}E A^{-1} \; .$$

Comment: Thanks Raskolnikov.  Since the matrix expansion would not be the same as scalar function expansion I guess, why we can omit the higher terms ?

Comment: You could argue that on the basis of some matrix norm. The expansion would then be valid for sufficiently small perturbations with respect to that matrix norm.